# Printing the output in numerical order in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have written a program which reads the last line of multiple files at once and prints the output as a list of tuples.

```
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join

    import subprocess
    path = "/home/abc/xyz/200/coord_b/"
    filename_last_lines = [[(filename, subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', path + 
    filename]))] for filename in [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and 
    f.endswith('.txt')]]

    print(filename_last_lines)
```

The output that I now get is (coord_70.txt, P), (coord_4.txt, R) and so on which is very random. I need to print this in numerical order as in (coord_1.txt, R), (coord_2.txt, R) and so on. Can you please suggest me changes to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply sorted() on listdir:

```
    filename_last_lines = [[(filename, subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', path + 
filename]))] for filename in [f for f in sorted(listdir(path)) if isfile(join(path, f)) and 
f.endswith('.txt')]]
```

Comment: This wil not sort in numerical order.

Comment: It will sort the file names alphabetically which seems to be good enough for this case (just printing).

Comment: @Roland Smith, It does sort numerically.

Comment: @accidental_coder Try `sorted([str(n) for n in range(1, 21)])` and you'll see that it doesn't.

Comment: You could use natsorted() from the natsort module for natural sorting if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to sort the filenames:

```
filename_last_lines = [[(filename, subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', path + 
    filename]))] for filename in sorted([f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and 
    f.endswith('.txt')])]
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to `sort` the list with a custom `key` function.

```
filename_last_lines.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0][6:-4]))
```

Let's decode what the lambda does.

Every element of the list is a tuple, so `x[0]` grabs the first element of the tuple, the filename.

Then we want to extract the number from the filename as an integer, so:

```
In [1]: x = ('coord_70.txt', 1)
Out[1]: ('coord_70.txt', 1)

In [2]: int(x[0][6:-4])
Out[2]: 70
```

Comment: Where do I add this line @Roland Smith?

Comment: Just before the `print`.

Comment: This will only work for file names with this specific pattern (6 chars before the number).